# Ionic 3 Android app to print on thermal printer similar to Receipt Printer in play store

Tags: angular, printing, bluetooth, ionic2

I am working on a project where it need to print receipt on thermal printer. 
Printer I am using is Everycom Thermal Printer Model-E200. I need to print it on the Bluetooth.

Finally I came to conclusion 99.9% it not possible with Ionic 3. But a app in the play store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.eetplus.print can connect to that printer. So 0.1% I am thinking we have some corner chance to resolve the issue.

I have tried with default printer plugin which didn't support for the printer I am using.

Comment: "I am expecting some help soon here" - ha, good luck with that attitude!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer/

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation on ionic 2 and above. It works on my bluetooth receipt printer. It uses serial connection. Give it a try:

https://github.com/razmans/ionicBluetoothPrint

Comment: Thanks Razman, Can you help me out on new requirement print via USB  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395373/ionic-2-print-function-to-pos-printer-using-usb-for-android

Comment: I am sorry keerthi, have not got to work on USB printing yet

Comment: hey @RazmanSarit your example will work for USB thermal printer ? can u please guide me ?

Comment: @KishanOza sorry for the really late response. No it will not