# Ionic 2 Print function to POS printer using USB

Tags: android, angular, printing, ionic2, ionic3

I need to develop the ionic android app which needs to be integrate with POS printer via USB. I was able to do the same with Bluetooth but when it come to USB connection i am totally zero on this.

I hope some one can help me out. I tried with https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/serial/ but no idea how this one gonna work.

Comment: Now i am able to open the port. It is not going to success or error. no response from the open function

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Comment: I have also same req

Comment: Has anyone managed to do this?